# What is the Japanese word for a judge in a court of law?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, english-to-japanese

I have looked up judge, but I am finding a number of words and am not sure how they are different. Is there a general word that is most common?

Words I found include:
saibankan    裁判官
saibannin    裁判人 
hanji        判事
houkan       法官
shichoku     司直

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The catch-all term for (proper) judges in the modern Japanese judicial system is 裁判官. There are also 裁判**員** ("lay judge / jury") for important cases.

Legally speaking, 判事 is a subclass of 裁判官. 判事 roughly refer to 裁判官 who are not 長官 ("chiefs") nor 判事補 ("assistant judges"). For example, Japanese 最高裁判所 (Supreme Court) has fifteen 裁判官's, which consist of one 最高裁判所**長官** and fourteen 最高裁判所**判事**. That being said, laypeople do not see the word 判事 very often. I may be mistaken, but I feel news articles for the general public usually use 裁判官 when they report domestic incidents. I see the word 判事 mainly from translations of foreign news and detective dramas.

Comment: この説明でもいいと思いますが、「裁判官」は訴訟法の主体で「判事」は行政法（裁判所法）の職位なのでは？例えば軍法会議で「裁判官」を務めるのは「判事」ではなく法曹資格を持つ将校、強制起訴の場合に「検察官」を務めるのは「検事」でなく弁護士、というように。本当は回答すべきなんでしょうが、自分の英語力では難しかったです。すみません。

Comment: 「被控訴人」という職業がないという話なら分かりますが、「裁判官」は職名として普通に通用するものではないでしょうか。名刺出しつつ「私は判事です」と言うのはOKで「私は裁判官です」と言うのはダメ…なんてことは多分ないですよね。現代日本の話だと思うので軍法会議とかは法律に定義すらないでしょうし。（あと簡裁判事絡みのツッコミが来そうですが、すみません、そこまでの話をしてもしょうがないので意図的に省きました）

Comment: what about 'saibanjou' or something? https://youtu.be/BTgTpkFZ4dE?t=320